# Drupal 8 Why isnt my theme finding style.css?

Tags: jquery, html, css, drupal, drupal-8

For some reason my theme cant find css/style.css in drupal 8.

This is the .info.yml:

```
name: Adminimal
type: theme
description: Drupal Administration Simplified.
# version: VERSION
# core: 8.x
base theme: seven

# Include CSS.
stylesheets:
  all:
    - css/style.css

# Information added by Drupal.org packaging script on 2014-10-23
version: '8.x-1.x-dev'
core: '8.x'
project: 'adminimal_theme'
datestamp: 1414059738
```

This is how the folders look like:

```
Theme/adminimal.info.yml
Theme/css/style.css
```

The css in the style.css file:

```
html{
    background-color: blue !important;
}
```

It doesnt even show up in the styles section in my google chrome console so i think it doesnt find the file but why?

And about jquery in drupal i cant manage to get this working: https://www.drupal.org/node/1541860 To work with: //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js How should i do this?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

This may be an obvious answer, but try clearing your css/js cache.

It should also be noted that the name of the theme folder should be the name of the theme. So instead of this:

```
Theme/adminimal.info.yml
Theme/css/style.css
```

You should have this:

```
adminimal/adminimal.info.yml
adminimal/css/style.css
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bug in core. Try the patch on this page: https://www.drupal.org/node/2389735

Also, CSS is now added using libraries. See https://www.drupal.org/theme-guide/8/assets

Answer (score 1):

Drupla 8 uses a different approach.

As far as I know you need a YOUR-THEME.libraries.yml file in which you then declare your css. In the info.yml you just point out what styling you from the libraries.yml-file you want. In this example the "global-styling".

adminimal.info.yml

```
libraries:
 -adminimal/global-styling
```

adminimal.libraries.yml

```
global-styling:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/style.css: {}
```

Be cautious with the spaces (no tabs are allowed). On the drupal-site this goes in more detail: https://www.drupal.org/node/2216195. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue I just resolved by using this which initially I didn't understand but I have it now working.

[Attaching a library in a Twig template](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme)

You can also attach an asset library to a Twig template by using the attach_library() Twig function. In any *.html.twig, you can do:

> {{ attach_library('fluffiness/cuddly-slider') }}
>
> Some fluffy markup {{ message }}
>
> You must also add the {{ attach_library(your_library) }} to your twig template in my case I added it to my sub-theme's html.html.twig file and I added it specially here .

Please note under:

> **BANDWIDTH OPTIMIZATION**
>   External resources can be optimized automatically, which can reduce both the size and number of requests made to your website.
>
> - Aggregate CSS files
> - Aggregate JavaScript files

these options may be selected Drupal caches the css files and if you have the CSS option selected you will end up with one big minified cache css file.